# Where is HTML renderer of View Results Tree hidden in Jmeter 2.13

Tags: html, jmeter, response, updates, hidden

Where is hidden HTML response renderer option? This happened to me after update jMeter to 2.13 r1665067.

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is on top of the old location in [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree), see screenshot:

[image: Renderers location]

Comment: Oooh, I´m blind as a bat. Burned half a day with this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 11):

It on the top 
Refer to this image.
[image]

Comment: This guy is the real MVP. Not like that "UBIK LOAD PACK" guy. I mean, come on: "Look up"? I'm on StackOverflow buddy, I need you to be my eyes.

Comment: @DavidS He updated his answer with image - seeing your comment!